# How to duplicate .doc page

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office

I have a microsoft word document with single page. I need to make more pages is that document that is the same as first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a reference to Microsoft Word, you can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to edit and create word documents.  The easiest way to copy pages is probably to create a new file and then insert the original file as many times as you need pages.
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object StartPoint = 0;

ApplicationClass WordApp = new ApplicationClass();
Document WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, 
                                         ref missing, ref missing);
Range MyRange = WordDoc.Range(ref StartPoint, ref missing);
```

Then use InsertFile with your original file as many times as you need pages.

Comment: I would like to add that repeatedly using InsertFile to the Range in this situation doesn't continually add pages. I've had success by collapsing the Range and adding PageBreak like so:
MyRange.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
    
Range MyRange = WordDoc.Range(ref StartPoint, ref missing);                          
MyRange.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
MyRange.InsertFile(filename);

Comment: `WordDoc.Range(ref StartPoint, ref missing);` will reset the range to contain whole document. How can this work? You need to keep the start position of `MyRange` and set the end of the range to be end of document.